# Changing column from varchar to integer and removing non-number character

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to update a version column in a table from VARCHAR to int.

The version column is currently saving versions as a combination of a "v" and a number (e.g. v1, v2, v3), and I would like to have it just be the number.

I tried to use this sql query to update the table column:

```
alter table vanities alter column version TYPE INTEGER USING(version::integer);
```

However, I got the following error:

```
[22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "v1"
```

Is there a SQL query I could use that would strip the column of all of the v characters and then convert it into an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try getting rid of the first character:

```
alter table vanities alter column version TYPE INTEGER USING (substr(version, 2)::integer);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=66f6a510e56ea1d0af0feb68e7b840fc) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @SeanSan, I'm glad you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too. (Plus, I want to see Gordon break a billion.)

Comment: @EricBrandt Just did. Sorry I didn't know!